# Does a new FAA medical supersede and void an old medical?

Tags: faa, medical

If this seems like a rant it's not intended to be, but an actual issue I'm facing.

Scenario: I've been on disability for about a year and a half, and I'm ready to get my Medical back and go back to work.  I've followed everything that ALPA my union said to do, and what the FAA has sent me in the process. AMAS (ALPA Medical) told me to get a deferred medical after I sent all my medical documents to the FAA.

I go to my AME and get a 1st class medical and pass it, but it has to be deferred, and the FAA has to approve it. So my AME sends it off to the FAA after a period of time I get a letter from them saying I need to go do another medical, so I go do another medical.  But it's been less than 90 days, so my AME cannot print out a medical, so he contacts the FAA again, they say they are sending my medical to me.  Several weeks later I get a medical that shows 10/17/22 for the date (original date I did the medical). It shows it was printed out the day before I got my second medical exam and mailed on 11/19/22 (according to date on the bottom of my medical paperwork).

I decided to look at my [PRIA](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/lic_cert/pria) information, and it shows 11/16/22 as my Medical date.  I know that's not the date my medical shows.

I call the FAA about my medical. After I spoke with someone I told my situation to, and she looked and didn't see an issue at first, but then she found the 2nd medical dated on 11/16/22 in the system.  She says contact my AME and see if he can print out the 2nd medical, and if he cannot print it have him call the FAA.  So I call my AME and his secretary says she can only find the original 10/17/22, they have not received anything else from the FAA and they don't want to deal with it, tell me to call the FAA. Grrrr...

Is my 10/17/22 medical legal to use even though I may have one with a date of 11/16/22?
I start indoc in a week for my job.  I don't want to get ramp/sim checked and have an issue... **Does a new medical supersede the old one and make the old one void?** They are both 1st class medicals.

I'm going to try calling the FAA again tomorrow, but I'm afraid they are going to say contact my AME again, and he's not going to be of any help.

Comment: I have no idea, the FAA's medical system is an enigma to me. You may get knowledgeable answers on this site (and I hope you do as I feel your pain), but your question's title uses the word opinion, and based questions are off topic so this could get closed. I suggest you reword it, and also edit it so it's a bit less of a rant, as TBH it's a little hard to follow.

Comment: I followed your advice, and rewrote it  somewhat..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for direct legal advice

Comment: May want to try the advice given in the answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6403/7532) and see if you can get a copy of the new medical that way.

Comment: That works for me @Brad, it sounds like you got a workable answer and it's good you posted it as it may help others.

Comment: Not an answer, but I suggest calling or emailing your Regional Flight Surgeon for a copy of the new cert.

Comment: I'd also write your Congressman/woman, this is the kind of runaround that the federal agencies are not supposed to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting the FAA today on this phone number: **405-954-4821** regarding my medical status. They concluded that my 10/17/22 medical is invalid because a new one has been issued on 11/16/22.

**Once a medical has been issued, the old one is invalid.**

Comment: Since (it sounds like) your new medical was issued by the FAA (rather than by an AME), was the FAA able to provide you with the replacement hard copy of it that you need?

Comment: Yes, they emailed me a copy of my medical.